# IE top-aligning text in input

Tags: css

The top input search [on my site here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) isn't correctly displaying in IE no matter what I've tried - I tried padding and line-height, but they're still aligned at the top.

Here's the CSS and any ideas would be great:

```
.search-bg {
background: #8A939A url("/images/top-input-bg.jpg") repeat;
border-radius: 15px;
display: block;
float: left;
height: 30px;
margin: 15px 10px 0 0;
width: 205px;
}

.search-bg input {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: none;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 15px;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
width: 154px;
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the value of `line-height` to 30 in input

```
.search-bg input {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: none;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px; <--
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
width: 154px;
}
```

Comment: @suedarby oops, didn't read the time stamp appropriately, didn't mean to jump the gun. Sry

Comment: No worries, yes it was because of the time limit - thanks again.